# I am struggling to write a transform python file for the tfx pipeline in transform component. I am working with object detection task

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-transform, tfx, mlops

I am building a pipeline using tensorflow extended. The dataset is already conversted to the tfrecord for the ingestion. I want to do data preprocessing such as scalin, data augmentation along with bbox and prepare data for the object detection model training. As per I understand TFX, this things has to be done in transform component. I am struggling in this part. If someone can suggest me an example or give some kind of hint how to move ahead then it would be very helpful.

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf
import tfx
from tfx.components.evaluator.component import Evaluator
from tfx.components.example_gen.import_example_gen.component import ImportExampleGen
from tfx.components.example_validator.component import ExampleValidator
from tfx.components.model_validator.component import ModelValidator
from tfx.components.pusher.component import Pusher
from tfx.components.schema_gen.component import SchemaGen
from tfx.components.statistics_gen.component import StatisticsGen
from tfx.components.trainer.component import Trainer
from tfx.components.transform.component import Transform
from tfx.orchestration.experimental.interactive.interactive_context import (
    InteractiveContext,
)
from tfx.proto import evaluator_pb2
from tfx.proto import example_gen_pb2
from tfx.proto import pusher_pb2
from tfx.proto import trainer_pb2
from tfx.v1 import proto

_dataset_tfrecord_path = ""
_pipeline_name = "od_pipeline"

output_conf = proto.Output(
    split_config=example_gen_pb2.SplitConfig(
        splits=[
            proto.SplitConfig.Split(name="train", hash_buckets=4),
            proto.SplitConfig.Split(name="eval", hash_buckets=1),
        ]
    )
)

example_gen = ImportExampleGen(input_base=_dataset_tfrecord_path, output_config=output_conf)

statistics_gen = StatisticsGen(examples=example_gen.outputs["examples"])

infer_schema = SchemaGen(statistics=statistics_gen.outputs["statistics"])

validate_stats = ExampleValidator(
    statistics=statistics_gen.outputs["statistics"], schema=infer_schema.outputs["schema"]
)

transform = Transform(
    examples=example_gen.outputs['examples'],
    schema=infer_schema.outputs['result'],
    module_file=TRANSFORM_MODULE
)
```

I have tried to find the solution online but couldn't get anything useful.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Before jumping into tfx Transform, I would first understand the tensorflow transform library, especially following the tutorial at https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/transform/get_started